# Can't get Xcode / JUCE / .gitignore to work

Tags: xcode, git, gitignore, juce

I'm placing my .gitignore file in the same location as the *.jucer file and the .gitignore file contains:

```
./Builds/*
./JuceLibraryCode/*
```

As I only want to back up the source code folder **only.**

But whenever I go to commit, tons of of folders and items inside the Builds and JuceLibraryCode folder are pre checked.  How Can I get Xcode to see this ignore file?  Is it in the wrong location since the Projucer builds the folder hierarchy in a way that Xcode doesn't understand?  I have it in the same location as my .git file.

Also, its worth noting that I recently allowed .git to back up everything, all of the files I'm currently trying to now ignore in those folders, but I did do a `git rm --cached` on all the files I'm trying to skip, as i read I needed to dump those before the .gitignore would be successful, but still, not luck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: make a commit removing the files you wanted ignored, they should no longer be tracked then

Comment: @OMGtechy - are you saying making a commit through Xcode and unchecking the items before committing?  Doing this should cause it to ignore those files?

Comment: What I'm saying is, if you've already got it in source control, you need to have a commit that removes them from source control before the .gitignore file will take effect :)

Answer (score 0):

- Remove git cache again.

  ```
  $ git rm --cached -r .
  ```
- Add this in `.gitignore`

  ```
  Builds/
  JuceLibraryCode/
  ```
- See if git ignore the changes

  ```
  $ git status
  ```

Comment: I've tried this as well, and a ton of other variations (I just tried this after you posted to double check / verify), but again, its not working.  Is there anything I have to do special to get Xcode to notice these changes?  there are no checkmarks next to the folders I have listed in the .gitignore (in fact, no checkmark box at all), but checkmarks for every item inside it.

Comment: As far I know nothing special for Xcode. Just add `.gitignore` file in root of project dir. Make sure you removing `git cached`. Can you run the commands sequentially of the answer.

Comment: I don't want to lose the current tracking of my source files and I think your first line will remove everything, I'll have to probably manually rm --cached with each file, though I did do this to begin with and the issue still persisted.